# Retrieve Schema From Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to retrieve schema subject versions given a kafka topic from a schema registry. I can successfully POST a new version with `client.register(schema-name, schema)`, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the versions. I tried below using a curl request, but the result hits -1 immediately (empty).

```
CachedSchemaRegistryClient client = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 20);

// curl -X GET http://schema.registry.url:8888/subjects/{topic}/versions/

String command = "curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json' 'https://schema.registry.url:8888/api/schema-proxy/subjects/mytopic-value/versions'";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
int result;
while ((result = reader.read()) != -1){ // Nothing printed
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

How can I fix this GET request, or better yet, how should I use the schema registry `client` to retrieve a schema?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using:

```
SchemaMetadata sm = client.getLatestSchemaMetadata(schemaName);
System.out.println(sm.getSchema());
```